# Find unique row compared to other entries in table

Tags: sql

I have following table:

```
+-ID-+-USER--+--VALUE--+
|1   |'userA'|'MOV-AAA'|
|2   |'userB'|'MOV-AAA'|
|3   |'userB'|'MOV-BBB'|
|4   |'userC'|'MOV-AAA'|
|5   |'userC'|'MOV-BBB'|
|6   |'userD'|'MOV-EEE'|
+----+-------+---------+
```

And I would like to find now ALL unique VALUE compared to 2 user. Like userA and userB. While comparing userA and userB I would expect MOV-BBB.

At the moment I have this query:

```
SELECT A.userName, A.value
FROM testTable A
WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT B.userName, B.value
        FROM testTable B
        WHERE B.value < A.value)
```

And receive this result:

```
userName    value
userB       MOV-BBB
userC       MOV-BBB
userD       MOV-EEE
```

Thank you

Comment: How come you want userD MOV-EEE returned, when 6 userD MOV-AAA is stored in the table?

Comment: Sorry my fault. Copy, paste error. Of course userD have MOV-EEE as VALUE.

Comment: I still don't get it, why MOV-BBB and not MOV-AAA for userB and userC? Why return row for userD but not for useA? What's the expected result???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.

Do you want to get unique values for a specified pair of users? if so, try this:

```
DECLARE @FirstUserName char(5),
        @SecondUserName char(5)

SELECT  @FirstUserName = 'userA',
        @SecondUserName = 'userB'

SELECT userName, cValue
FROM testTable A
WHERE (UserName = @FirstUserName OR UserName = @SecondUserName)
AND Value NOT IN (
  SELECT Value
  FROM testTable
  WHERE (UserName = @FirstUserName OR UserName = @SecondUserName)
  AND UserName <> A.UserName
);
```

Do you want to get the results for the first user of specified pair of users? if so, this will do the trick:

```
DECLARE @FirstUserName char(5),
        @SecondUserName char(5)

SELECT  @FirstUserName = 'userA',
        @SecondUserName = 'userB'


SELECT userName, cValue
FROM testTable A
WHERE (UserName = @FirstUserName)
AND Value NOT IN (
  SELECT Value
  FROM testTable
  WHERE UserName = @SecondUserName
);
```

Or maybe you want to get unique values for any users at all? in this case, try this:

```
SELECT userName, cValue
FROM testTable A
WHERE cValue NOT IN (
  SELECT cValue
  FROM testTable
  WHERE UserName <> A.UserName
);
```

[Here, play around with it yourself. (sql fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3678/1)

Comment: Thank you @Tohar Peled. Yes its this: "Do you want to get unique values for a specified pair of users?" I've tried it and it works like I've imagined. Will try to improve my english also like my sql knowledge ;)